# Multidimensional lists and their dependency

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a question about removing the dependency in multidimensional lists in python.

Currently I have a (simplified) code snippet out of my bigger script:

```
mylist = [ 1,2,3 ]
listreplaced = mylist
listreplaced[0]="test"
print mylist

mylist = [ 1,2,3 ]
listreplaced = list(mylist)
listreplaced[0]="test"
print mylist

#Here it gets tricky
mylist = [ [ 1,2,3 ] ]
listreplaced = list(mylist)
listreplaced[0][0] = "test"
print mylist

mylist = [ [ 1,2,3 ] ]
listreplaced = list(mylist[0])
listreplaced[0] = "test"
print mylist
```

Which outputs:

```
[['test', 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[['test', 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

As you can see the third example also replaces the first value in the multidimensional list. What I want to do is: no matter how many dimensions the list has, I want a function to make it independent of the lists it was based on. The code would be something like this then:

```
mylist = [ [ 1,2,3 ] ]
listreplaced = makeIndependentList(mylist)
listreplaced[0][0] = "test"
print mylist
```

and the result should be `[[1, 2, 3]]` instead of `[['test', 2, 3]]`.
Does anyone have any ideas about how to write such a function? It should work **regardless of the number of dimensions of the list**, so if I have a list `[ [ [ [ [ [ 1,2,3 ] ] ] ] ] ]` it should still become independent on **all levels**.

Thanks in advance,

Jef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just use the copy module ... thats what its there for ...

```
 from copy import deepcopy

 my_other_list = deepcopy(my_list)
```

Comment: Very nice, works like a charm. But as I'm learning python: Imagine that you would want to write such a function yourself, how would you do such a thing? (I know it is like reinventing the wheel, but it's just a matter of interest, because, honestly: I wouldn't know)

Comment: you can copy a list with a slice `a_list[:]` would return a copy of the list ... so you would need to iteratively return slices until you got to non-mutable data types